# How to search and substitute inside Vim?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

Is there a way to specifically search for a pattern first and then replace using %s

Why I specifically chose vim is because I can easily make change using :wq

Consider I got a file abc.txt where I need to replace all two's with three:

```
cat abc.txt
one two
two two
one two
```

But I only need to replace only those lines that is having "one".
Is there a way to first grep or filter lines having "one" inside vim and then replace using
:%s/two/three/g.
I need a one-liner command that can filter out all lines having "one" and perform substitution.

Sample output

```
cat abc.txt
one three
two two
one three
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you need `sed`. also you can match on some string but only change parts of it. so no need for filtering with `grep` first.

Comment: You could use a captured group to meet your need (e.g. `:%s/\(one\) two/\1 three/`).

Comment: @PatrickBacon You should post that as answer

Comment: `:g/one/s/two/three/g` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell This actually worked! Please post this as an answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Use a Capture Group or a Look Behind Pattern to Solve Substitution**

This ex command should meet your needs:

```
:`%s/\(one\) two/\1 three/
```

---

This is also a classic look behind pattern matching problem (:help /@<=).

```
:%s/\(one\)\@<= two/ three/
```

---

Another approach might be to use `\zs`, `\ze` pattern matching technique. Look up `:help \zs`.

```
%s/one \zstwo\ze/three/
```